# ARM assembly not working without .type macro

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32

I am learning some (ARMv6-M) assembler for an STM32F0 (ARM Cortex M0) microcontroller. For starters, I wrote a script where I initialize register `r0` to `0` and `r1` to `1`, finally, `r0` is incremented by `1` in a loop. Using a debugger, i.e. `gdb`, I can use `si` to run one step and `info reg` to output the registers. The assembler code is given below,

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m0
.fpu softvfp
.thumb

.global vector_table
.global reset_handler

.type vector_table, %object
vector_table:
    .word _estack
    .word reset_handler

.type reset_handler, %function
reset_handler:
    LDR r0, =0
    LDR r1, =1

    main_loop:
        ADDS r0, r0, 1
    B main_loop
```

and is based on [this excellent tutorial](https://vivonomicon.com/2018/04/02/bare-metal-stm32-programming-part-1-hello-arm/).

When I remove the `.type x` macros, I don't see any changes in the registers through my debuggers, however according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423211/when-are-gas-elf-the-directives-type-thumb-size-and-section-needed) the `.type`-macro should have no effect.

**Why do the register `r0` and `r1` remain constant when I remove the `.type`-macros?**

Comment: Verify your vector table. My guess is that without the `.type` the entry does not have the LSB set which would be needed to mark the function as thumb. So it will be interpreted as ARM and it will probably decode as some entirely unrelated instruction.

Comment: @Jester Can you elaborate? I only have a linker script where I define `MEMORY { ... }` and `_estack`.

Comment: it is armv6-m definitely not armv6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m0
.fpu softvfp
.thumb

.global vector_table
.global reset_handler

.type vector_table, %object
vector_table:
    .word 0x20001000
    .word reset_handler

.type reset_handler, %function
reset_handler:
    LDR r0, =0
    LDR r1, =1
```

with the .type function

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <vector_table>:
    1000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
    1004:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

00001008 <reset_handler>:
    1008:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (100c <reset_handler+0x4>)
    100a:   4901        ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; (1010 <reset_handler+0x8>)
    100c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1010:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
```

the vector table for reset has the proper address ORRed with 1 0x1009.  If you remove the function declaration

```
disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <vector_table>:
    1000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
    1004:   00001008    andeq   r1, r0, r8

00001008 <reset_handler>:
    1008:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (100c <reset_handler+0x4>)
    100a:   4901        ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; (1010 <reset_handler+0x8>)
    100c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1010:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
```

you get a binary that won't boot on a cortex-m.  For thumb you can also use .thumb_func and the next label found is considered a function:

```
.thumb_func
reset_handler:
    LDR r0, =0
    LDR r1, =1
```

and you are good again, the binary will work:

```
so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <vector_table>:
    1000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
    1004:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

00001008 <reset_handler>:
    1008:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (100c <reset_handler+0x4>)
    100a:   4901        ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; (1010 <reset_handler+0x8>)
    100c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1010:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
```

This is also required for thumb interwork if you want gnu(s linker) to trampoline between functions for you:

```
.syntax unified
.cpu arm7tdmi
.thumb

.global vector_table
.global reset_handler

.type vector_table, %object
vector_table:
    .word 0x20001000
    .word reset_handler

.thumb_func
reset_handler:
    LDR r0, =0
    LDR r1, =1
    bl hello

.arm

.type hello, %function
hello:
    b reset_handler
```

gives

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <vector_table>:
    1000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
    1004:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

00001008 <reset_handler>:
    1008:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (1014 <hello+0x4>)
    100a:   4903        ldr r1, [pc, #12]   ; (1018 <hello+0x8>)
    100c:   f000 f80e   bl  102c <__hello_from_thumb>

00001010 <hello>:
    1010:   ea000002    b   1020 <__reset_handler_from_arm>
    1014:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1018:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
    101c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00001020 <__reset_handler_from_arm>:
    1020:   e59fc000    ldr r12, [pc]   ; 1028 <__reset_handler_from_arm+0x8>
    1024:   e12fff1c    bx  r12
    1028:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

0000102c <__hello_from_thumb>:
    102c:   4778        bx  pc
    102e:   e7fd        b.n 102c <__hello_from_thumb>
    1030:   eafffff6    b   1010 <hello>
    1034:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

otherwise

```
.arm

hello:
    b reset_handler
```

gives non-functional code

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <vector_table>:
    1000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
    1004:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

00001008 <reset_handler>:
    1008:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (1014 <hello+0x4>)
    100a:   4903        ldr r1, [pc, #12]   ; (1018 <hello+0x8>)
    100c:   f000 f800   bl  1010 <hello>

00001010 <hello>:
    1010:   ea000002    b   1020 <__reset_handler_from_arm>
    1014:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1018:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
    101c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00001020 <__reset_handler_from_arm>:
    1020:   e59fc000    ldr r12, [pc]   ; 1028 <__reset_handler_from_arm+0x8>
    1024:   e12fff1c    bx  r12
    1028:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9
    102c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

now on a cortex-m you have no arm mode so no interworking, but for the vector table and any other functions in assembly language you want to call from C or other high level you need to have the function declaration.

The object declaration I have never seen, have been using gnu tools since around the time arm was added and have been doing bare metal boot the chip stuff without needing it...So cant help you there.

The reason why they are remaining constant is because you hung the chip or forced it into a handler which you didnt define so yet again hung the chip.  the processor status should have changed to indicate the fault mode you are in.

Comment: lol, you linked an answer of mine, I generally never follow links in questions, but came back and got curious, maybe I will read my prior answer again some day...maybe I am contradicting my former self with my current self...

Comment: In your answer, you wrote, "the vector table for reset has the proper address ORRed with 1 0x1009". Does the ARM standard demand that the reset handler address has to be ORRed? Where do I find the specification for this?

Comment: it is in the arm architectural reference manual for the core.  yes all vectors.

Comment: For reference, I found the vector table to be described in 2.3.4 of the [Generic User Guide for Cortex-M0 Devices](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/DUI0497A_cortex_m0_r0p0_generic_ug.pdf).

Comment: What was implied there is you should have read the docs before asking the question not after.  What you didnt know perhaps is you should stick to the ARM TRM technical reference manual for the core, and the ARM ARM, the architectural reference manual for the architecture.  Their other manuals like the programmers/users guides I have seen to be incorrect or misleading. (as other SO questions have demonstrated)  YMMV.

Comment: The entry at offset 0 is used to initialize the value for SP_main, see The SP registers on page B1-186. All other entries must have bit [0] set to 1